# I would like to copy paste a file and then rename it, how do i do it in my case?

Tags: copy, rename, copy-paste, file-rename

I have many orderly numbered files (001~099) containing the same file called "red". All these file are in one directory. I want to copy all the "red" files into one folder (global) and each "red" file i move i want to rename it by its parent folder e.g. 001, 002..etc..

I know that how to copy move and rename but i dont know how to put them together

So i did

cp ~/00*/red ~/global
mv red 001

I want to make it into a loop and add +1 to 001 everytime a file is added but i failed

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in {1..99}
do
  number=$(printf "%03d" $i)

  cp ~/$number/red ~/global/$number
done
```

In bash `>=bash-4` this might work as well:

```
for number in {001..099}
do
  cp ~/$number/red ~/global/$number
done
```

Comment: Thank you so much, ill try it!

Answer (score 1):

This bash script should do what you've described:

```
for i in {1..99}
do
  NUMBER="$(printf "%03d" $i)"
  cp ~/$NUMBER/red ~/global/$NUMBER
done
```

In each iteration of the loop, the variable $NUMBER gets assigned the output of the printf command (which prints the value of i, formatted with appropriate 0-padding in the front). Then $NUMBER is used to specify the directory names from 001 to 099.

EDIT: whoops, looks like Stefan beat me to it

Comment: Thank you for your help!